# User confirmation script not working even though it should PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have yet another problem. However this time its with the user confirmation. After the users register they recieve an email with the link mydomain.co.uk/confirm.php?username=(username)&id=(id). Everything there works, however even when the id and username are correct the users are still not being confirmed. Heres the script:

```
<?php
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
    $username = $_REQUEST['username'];
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'website', 'mypasswordtroll');
    if(!$link) {
    die('could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    $db_selected = mysql_select_db('website', $link);
    if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Cant use database : ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM unconfirmedusers WHERE username = '$username' and id = $id");
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0){
    $continue = false;
    }
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $usr = $row['username'];
    $pass = $row['password'];
    $email = $row['email'];
    $day = $row['day'];
    $month = $row['month'];
    $year = $row['year'];
    }
    if($continue == false){
    echo '<div class="alert alert-error"><b>Oh man!</b> No such user or id found!</div>';
    echo $result;
    }else{
    $query2 = "DELETE FROM unconfirmedusers WHERE id='$id' and username='$username'";
    $query3 = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, day, month, year) VALUES ('$usr', '$pass', '$email', $day, $month, $year)";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
    $result3 = mysql_query($query3);
    echo '<div class="alert alert-success"><b>Great! </b>You can now log in!</div>';
    }
    ?>
```

I can not find anything wrong with it and I have no idea which part is incorrect... Can anyone spot any errors that will help me with this?

Comment: You need immediately stop using this code. It is vulnerable to SQL injection. [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Have you thought about adding some checking in to your queries so you can check to see if there are any errors when you run them?

Comment: Does your editor ask you more money when you want to indent your code properly ? If no, feel obliged to do it. You will thanks me later.

Comment: I dont use any editor on my pc, i just use putty straight to the server,

Comment: Also, how can I protect my code from sql injection? Is there any tutorial i could read up on (i am a beginner)

Comment: -1 read what people gives you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$continue == false` will always be true, because you never set `$continue`. If a variable `$var` is not set, then `($var == false)` will always return true. `($var === false)`, on the other hand, will return `true` only if you explicitly set `$var` to `false`.

You either need to change that line to `if($continue === false)`, or you need to add `$continue = true;` before the check to see if there are any results.

That said, as FreshPrinceOfSO commented, you need to revamp this code and do some research on MySQL injection. Additionally, I should note that the mysql functions are deprecated and you should use MySQLi instead.